# YPDrawSignatureView empty

Tags: ios, swift, github, boolean

I am trying to use [YPDrawSignatureView](https://github.com/GJNilsen/YPDrawSignatureView). It has been working fine for me so far, but now I am trying to detect whether the user has signed or not. Here is my code for that:

```
if signatureView.containsSignature == false {
```

However, I always get `false` even if I have signed already. How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: I tested the demo app included in the repository, and there the code works properly. Maybe you neglected something while hooking it up?

Answer (score 0):

If you hook it up as in the example project, it should work properly. The documentation also shows how to do this.